# FullPage.js fade effect on desktop, disable and get default scroll on smaller devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js

I’m using SliceJack 
[FullPage.js fade effect code snippet](https://slicejack.com/fullpage-js-slide-fade-effect/) (1st one) to get the transitions effects on my website, which works perfect and I’m happy with them on desktop (put them into my main css).

I want to disable the effects on smaller devices such as Ipad and mobile, so I can scroll default (normal) without transitions.

Only option for me to disable the effects is by removing the code snippet (1st one) but than I lose those effects on desktop aswell.

I have enabled responsivewidth at 976 pixels in jQuery.fullPage.js script.

Is it possible to empty those 3 classes I added in CSS (for transitions) on mobile and iPad?

```css
/*Fade in effect & one pager*/
.fullpage-wrapper {
 width: 100%!important;
 transform: none!important;
}

.fp-section {
 width: 100%!important;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.fp-section.active {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 1;
}
/* Remove transition when website is still loading */
body {display:none}
body[class*="fp-viewing-"] {display:block}
```

Comment: This code fades out the first section on scroll the following sections do not fade in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making use of [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and the [fadingEffect extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/fading-effect.html), then you can make use of fullPage.js callbacks and functions to solve this in the proper way:

```
$('#fullpage').fullPage({
    responsiveWidth: 976,
    afterResponsive: function(isResponsive){
        if(isResponsive){
            $.fn.fullpage.fadingEffect.turnOff();
        }
        else{
            $.fn.fullpage.fadingEffect.turnOn();
        }
    }
});
```